Issues changing variable value within an Azure DevOps pipeline stage
I'm seeking assistance from the community to resolve this issue. I'm attempting to modify the value of an externally defined variable, which will be initialized to false by default. However, if the 'if' condition is validated, the value should be changed to true, which will then control the subsequent stages.
name: terraform_tests_pipeline_environment

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - Environments/Dev/*

variables:
  dev_changed: 'false'

stages:
- stage: DetectChanges
  displayName: 'Detect Changes'
  jobs:
    - job: CheckDevChanges
      displayName: 'Check Dev Folder Changes'
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

        - task: Bash@3
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              archivos_modificados='Environments/Dev/readme.md'
              if echo "$archivos_modificados" | grep -q "Environments/Dev/"; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]true"
              else
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]false"
              fi
              echo $archivos_modificados
              echo "$(dev_changed)"
          displayName: 'Detect Changes in dev Folder'

- stage: Dev
  displayName: 'Deploy Dev Environment'
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['dev_changed'], 'true'))
  jobs:
    - job: TerraformDeployDev
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Checking for changes in the 'dev' folder"
          displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'

I expect that when passing through the if statement, if it is true, the variable will change to true, so that the condition in the other stage can continue. However, when I print the variable's value, it is not changing

From your description, you need to update the variable value in the DetectChanges stage and then pass the updated value to next stages.
The variable in the DetectChanges stage can not be directly passed to the next stages.
To meet your requirement, you need to use the cross stages variable in Pipeline.
Here is an example:
name: terraform_tests_pipeline_environment

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - Environments/Dev/*

variables:
  dev_changed: 'false'

stages:
- stage: DetectChanges
  displayName: 'Detect Changes'
  jobs:
    - job: CheckDevChanges
      displayName: 'Check Dev Folder Changes'
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

        - task: Bash@3
          name: test
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              archivos_modificados='Environments/Dev/readme.md'
              if echo "$archivos_modificados" | grep -q "Environments/Dev/"; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]true"
              else
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]false"
              fi
              echo $archivos_modificados
              echo "$(dev_changed)"
          displayName: 'Detect Changes in dev Folder'

- stage: Dev
  displayName: 'Deploy Dev Environment'
  dependsOn: DetectChanges
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.DetectChanges.outputs['CheckDevChanges.test.dev_changed'], 'true'))
  jobs:
    - job: TerraformDeployDev
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Checking for changes in the 'dev' folder"
          displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'

Or you can use the variables field to define the dev_changed variable in Dev stage to get the value passed from the previous stage.
Here is an example:
name: terraform_tests_pipeline_environment

trigger:
  paths:
    include:
      - Environments/Dev/*

variables:
  dev_changed: 'false'

stages:
- stage: DetectChanges
  displayName: 'Detect Changes'
  jobs:
    - job: CheckDevChanges
      displayName: 'Check Dev Folder Changes'
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

        - task: Bash@3
          name: test
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              archivos_modificados='Environments/Dev/readme.md'
              if echo "$archivos_modificados" | grep -q "Environments/Dev/"; then
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]true"
              else
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]false"
              fi
              echo $archivos_modificados
              echo "$(dev_changed)"
          displayName: 'Detect Changes in dev Folder'

- stage: Dev
  displayName: 'Deploy Dev Environment'
  variables:
    dev_changed: $[dependencies.DetectChanges.outputs['CheckDevChanges.test.dev_changed']]
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['dev_changed'], 'true'))
  jobs:
    - job: TerraformDeployDev
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Checking for changes in the 'dev' folder"
          displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'

Result:
The value of the variable: dev_changed is true.

The value of the variable: dev_changed is false.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Use outputs in a different stage

issue 1: the variable will be available to downstream steps within the same job, not the current step.
issue 2: wrong expression in Dev stage.
here is a sample code which been modified from your provided.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  dev_changed: 'false'

stages:
- stage: DetectChanges
  displayName: 'Detect Changes'
  jobs:
    - job: CheckDevChanges
      displayName: 'Check Changes'
      steps:
        - checkout: self
          persistCredentials: true

        - task: Bash@3
          name: 'outputVar'
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              if [ "aaa" == "aaa" ]; then
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]true"
              else
                  echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dev_changed;isoutput=true]false"
              fi
          displayName: 'Detect Changes in with number'

        - bash: |
            echo $(outputVar.dev_changed)
- stage: Dev
  dependsOn: 
    - DetectChanges
  variables:
    myStageAVar: $[dependencies.DetectChanges.outputs['CheckDevChanges.outputVar.dev_changed']]
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.myStageAVar, 'true'))
  displayName: 'Deploy Dev Environment'
  jobs:
    - job: TerraformDeployDev
      displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Checking for changes in the 'dev' folder"
          displayName: 'Terraform Plan and Apply Dev'

